# Java scanner - Using a new line as a delimeter, but not a blank space?

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, delimiter

Assuming I have two lines of text like this:

```
sam|y|rutgers
jane|y|penn state
```

My current scanner would report:

```
sam|y|rutgers
jane|y|penn
state
```

instead of keeping the penn state together.

Is there any way I can specify the delimeter settings to include the new line, but not a space?

Comment: `Scanner` has a [`useDelimiter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#useDelimiter(java.util.regex.Pattern)) method. It also has a [`nextLine`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextLine()) method. In short, read [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html).

Answer (score 0):

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(...);
String val = scan.nextLine();
```

This would set the delimiter as the newline.

Comment: That is incorrect.  That doesn't change the current delimiter at all so it doesn't answer the question.